# Checking for exact matches in two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries, some consisting of data, and one having values I want to check match in the data dictionaries.

```
data = {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3', d: '4', e: '5', f: '6', g: '7'}
desiredValues = {b: '2', e: '1', g: '7'}
```

For the matching keys in each dictionary, I want to compare the values and see if they match or not. If 1 or more of the values doesn't match, I want to know which ones. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to have some sort of setup where I could compare multiple dictionaries of data to the single desired values dictionary and get an output for each one along the lines of:

```
b = True
e = False
g = True
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question! Sorry if it's rather simple, I just haven't been able to find a clear way to do this yet.

Comment: This seems like a simple loop `for key, value in desiredValues.items():` loop.

Comment: Inside the loop you check if the key is in `data` and the value matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through `desiredValues`, then check if the key is in `data` using `data[key]` where `key` is the current key from `desiredValues`:

```
data = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7'}
desiredValues = {'b': '2', 'e': '1', 'g': '7', 'z':'shouldn\'t be in data'} 

for key, value in sorted(desiredValues.items(), key=lambda i: i[0]):
    if key in data:
        print('{}:'.format(key), value == data[key])
    else:
        print('{}:'.format(key), 'not in data')
```

Output:

```
b: True
e: False
g: True
z: not in data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
for k in desiredValues:
    print(f' {k}={data[k]==desiredValues[k]}')
```

Output:

```
 b=True
 e=False
 g=True
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to check membership by iterating over `desiredValues`'s `dict_items` and building a `set` from `data` for a faster lookup:

```
set_data = set(data.items()) 

[i in set_data for i in desiredValues.items()]
# [True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic `for` loop with `if` condition would do the trick:

```
In [144]: for key ,value in desiredValues.items(): 
     ...:     if desiredValues[key] == data[key]: 
     ...:         print('{}= True'.format(key)) 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         print('{}= False'.format(key)) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
b= True
e= False
g= True
```

### OR

```
In [143]: for key, value in data.items(): 
     ...:     if key in desiredValues: 
     ...:         if data[key] == desiredValues[key]: 
     ...:             print('{}= True'.format(key)) 
     ...:         else: 
     ...:             print('{}= False'.format(key)) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
b= True
e= False
g= True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(data.keys() & desiredValues.keys()) # the intersection of keys sets
for key, _ in data.items():
    if key in desiredValues:
        print(f'{key}: True')
    else:
        print(f'{key}: False')
```

output:

```
{'g', 'b', 'e'}
a: False
b: True
c: False
d: False
e: True
f: False
g: True
```